# Angular Univeral SSR - 3rd party library window undefined

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-ssr, web3modal

I am trying to setup an Angular Universal Project with SSR, everything works fine but when I try to use a 3rd party library via a Service it errors out with  `window is not defined`, the Library causing issue is called Web3Modal.

Is there some way to ignore a service or a method in a service from compilation for the SSR server build ? I basically need this code not to exist serverside and the methods to return nothing so that it will compile and serve.

my service which the issue gets triggered is the `new Web3Modal` constructor

```
import {Inject, Injectable, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import Web3Modal from "web3modal";
import WalletConnectProvider from "@walletconnect/web3-provider";
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Web3Service {
  web3Modal: any;

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: object,
    // @Inject(WEB3) private web3: Web3
    ) {
      if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        this.initWeb3Modal()
      }
    }
  
  initWeb3Modal(){
      if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
    const providerOptions = {
      walletconnect: {
        package: WalletConnectProvider, // required
        options: {
          infuraId: '', // required change this with your own infura id
          description: 'Scan the qr code and sign in',
          qrcodeModalOptions: {
            mobileLinks: [
              'rainbow',
              'metamask',
              'argent',
              'trust',
              'imtoken',
              'pillar'
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      injected: {
        display: {
          logo: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/36/MetaMask_Fox.svg',
          name: 'metamask',
          description: "Connect with the provider in your Browser"
        },
        package: null
      },
    };

    this.web3Modal = new Web3Modal({
      network: "mainnet", // optional change this with the net you want to use like rinkeby etc
      cacheProvider: true, // optional
      providerOptions, // required
      theme: {
        background: "rgb(39, 49, 56)",
        main: "rgb(199, 199, 199)",
        secondary: "rgb(136, 136, 136)",
        border: "rgba(195, 195, 195, 0.14)",
        hover: "rgb(16, 26, 32)"
      }
    });
  }    
  }

  
}
```

the exact lines where the error is triggered is here

```
...
Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",
{value:!0}),t.updateLocal=t.removeLocal=t.getLocal=t.setLocal=t.local=void 0;
var i2=n(0);n(10).isLocalStorageAvailable()&&
(t.local=window.localStorage),t.setLocal=function(e2,n2){var 
i3=JSON.stringify(n2);t.local&&t.local.setItem(e2,i3)},t.getLocal=function(e2){var 
n2=null,i3=null;if(t.local&&(i3=t.local.getItem(e2)),
....
```

my server.ts file

```
    import 'localstorage-polyfill'
    import { existsSync } from 'fs'
    import { join } from 'path'

    import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node'
    import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine'
    import express from 'express'

    import { createWindow } from 'domino'
    const indexHtml = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/angular-starter/browser/index.html')
    const win = createWindow(indexHtml)

    // Polyfills
    ;(global as any).window = win;
    ;(global as any).document = win.document;
    ;(global as any).navigator = win.navigator;

    (window as any).global = win;

    global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
    (global as any).localStorage = localStorage;

    // needs to be after window definition
    import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';

    import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common'

    // The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
    export function app(): express.Express {
      global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
      (window as any).global = win;
      const server = express()
      const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/angular-starter/browser')
      const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html'))
        ? 'index.original.html'
        : 'index'

      // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
      // server.engine('html', (_, options: { req: any }, callback) => {
      //   const engine = ngExpressEngine({
      //     bootstrap: AppServerModule,
      //     providers: [
      //       { provide: 'request', useFactory: () => options.req as any, deps: [] }
      //     ]
      //   })
      //   engine(_, options, callback)
      // })
      
      server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
        bootstrap: AppServerModule,
      }));

      server.set('view engine', 'html')
      server.set('views', distFolder)

      // Example Express Rest API endpoints
      // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
      // Serve static files from /browser
      server.get(
        '*.*',
        express.static(distFolder, {
          maxAge: '1y'
        })
      )

      // All regular routes use the Universal engine
      server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.render(indexHtml, {
          req,
          providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }]
        })
      })

      return server
    }

    function run(): void {
      const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000

      // Start up the Node server
      const server = app()
      server.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
      })
    }

    // Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
    // '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
    // The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
    declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire
    const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main
    const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || ''
    if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
      run()
    }
    export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: Did you try with `if (!isPlatformServer(this.platformId))` instead of `isPlatformBrowser`?